# What is the usage of the following code fragment [!= N'']

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  
    A0.ItemCode AS 'ItemCode',  
    A1.U_TrnWhs AS 'TrnWhs'
FROM        OITM A0
INNER JOIN  OCRD A1 ON A0.CardCode = A1.CardCode
AND ISNULL(A1.U_TrnWhs,'') != N''
```

Comment: And `!=` is an ancient and deprecated way to write `<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!= N''` will give you same result as `! = ''` .

**N means here => declaring the string as nvarchar data type, rather than varchar**

**N stands for => National language character set**

Its simply checking blank data.

```
SELECT  
    A0.ItemCode AS 'ItemCode',  
    A1.U_TrnWhs AS 'TrnWhs'
FROM        OITM A0
INNER JOIN  OCRD A1 ON A0.CardCode = A1.CardCode
AND ISNULL(A1.U_TrnWhs,'') != N'' --NOT equal to blank data
```

OR

```
SELECT  
    A0.ItemCode AS 'ItemCode',  
    A1.U_TrnWhs AS 'TrnWhs'
FROM        OITM A0
INNER JOIN  OCRD A1 ON A0.CardCode = A1.CardCode
AND ISNULL(A1.U_TrnWhs,'') != '' --NOT equal to blank data
```

Comment: Thank you Pankaj, it is easier to understand with your explanation and after realizing that  [!=] means [<>] in programming. I am a beginner in this.

Answer (score 1):

`N''` mean empty NVARCHAR string, so this condition mean that A1.U_TrnWhs is not null (becaouse ISNULL) and not empty.

Comment: Thank for your time and explanation Leszek.